# Kernel does not boot when using u-boot falcon mode (Beaglebone Black)

Tags: embedded-linux, beagleboneblack, u-boot

I am trying to improve the boot time of my custom Linux kernel on a Beaglebone Black. Up until now I have used the 'out the box' configured u-boot (version 2013.10) which adds about 3 seconds onto the booting process (even with the countdown removed). I have since discovered falcon mode and I have managed to follow the steps in the provided help file (in docs/readme.falcon) - I am using an SD card with a FAT partition and a root-fs partition.

I have followed the instructions to write my image (uImage) and device tree to the FAT partition but when I try to boot the kernel all I get is the following output and the kernel doesn't boot:

```
U-Boot SPL 2013.10 (Mar 30 2017 - 09:09:35)
reading args
reading uImage
reading uImage
```

However, if I break into u-boot proper and manually boot the kernel it's fine:

```
U-Boot# mmc rescan
U-Boot# fatload mmc 0:1 ${loadaddr} uImage
reading uImage
3617728 bytes read in 340 ms (10.1 MiB/s)
U-Boot# run findfdt
U-Boot# fatload mmc 0:1 ${fdtaddr} ${fdtfile}
reading am335x-boneblack.dtb
34925 bytes read in 9 ms (3.7 MiB/s)
U-Boot# run mmcargs
U-Boot# bootm ${loadaddr} - ${fdtaddr}
## Booting kernel from Legacy Image at 80200000 ...
   Image Name:   Linux-3.12.10
   Image Type:   ARM Linux Kernel Image (uncompressed)
   Data Size:    3617664 Bytes = 3.5 MiB
   Load Address: 80008000
   Entry Point:  80008000
   Verifying Checksum ... OK
## Flattened Device Tree blob at 80f80000
   Booting using the fdt blob at 0x80f80000
   Loading Kernel Image ... OK
   Using Device Tree in place at 80f80000, end 80f8b86c

Starting kernel ...
```

The only thing I can see is the the memory 'end' address of 0x80f8b86c is different to the output I get from the 'spl export' command:

```
U-Boot# spl export fdt ${loadaddr} - ${fdtaddr}
## Booting kernel from Legacy Image at 80200000 ...
   Image Name:   Linux-3.12.10
   Image Type:   ARM Linux Kernel Image (uncompressed)
   Data Size:    3617664 Bytes = 3.5 MiB
   Load Address: 80008000
   Entry Point:  80008000
   Verifying Checksum ... OK
## Flattened Device Tree blob at 80f80000
   Booting using the fdt blob at 0x80f80000
   Loading Kernel Image ... OK
   Using Device Tree in place at 80f80000, end 80f8b86c
subcommand not supported
subcommand not supported
   Using Device Tree in place at 80f80000, end 80f8e86c
Argument image is now in RAM: 0x80f80000
```

So it's at '....e86c' instead of '....b86c' - does this matter? Or is the kernel not booting because of some other reason?

****Edit****
As requested by Tom, below is the full log of the uboot commands I used. NOTE: I changed the device tree so the end address is now different to the above.

```
U-Boot# load mmc 0:1 ${loadaddr} uImage
reading uImage
3664576 bytes read in 340 ms (10.3 MiB/s)
U-Boot# run findfdt
U-Boot# load mmc 0:1 ${fdtaddr} ${fdtfile}
reading am335x-boneblack.dtb
37124 bytes read in 8 ms (4.4 MiB/s)
U-Boot# run mmcargs
U-Boot# spl export fdt ${loadaddr} - ${fdtaddr}
## Booting kernel from Legacy Image at 80200000 ...
   Image Name:   Linux-3.12.10
   Image Type:   ARM Linux Kernel Image (uncompressed)
   Data Size:    3664512 Bytes = 3.5 MiB
   Load Address: 80008000
   Entry Point:  80008000
   Verifying Checksum ... OK
## Flattened Device Tree blob at 80f80000
   Booting using the fdt blob at 0x80f80000
   Loading Kernel Image ... OK
   Using Device Tree in place at 80f80000, end 80f8c103
subcommand not supported
subcommand not supported
   Using Device Tree in place at 80f80000, end 80f8f103
Argument image is now in RAM: 0x80f80000
U-Boot# fatwrite mmc 0:1 0x80f80000 args f103
writing args
61699 bytes written
```

From my limited knowledge of u-boot I'm setting the bootargs when running 'run mmcargs' - this runs the below commands (again, these are the standard out of the box ones that came with the beaglebone configuration):

```
setenv bootargs console=${console} " \
${optargs} " \
"root=${mmcroot} " \
"rootfstype=${mmcrootfstype}\0" \
```

Where console is ttyO0 115200, optargs = '0', mmcroot='/dev/mmcblk0p2 ro' and mmcrootfstype='ext4 rootwait'. These are the standard bootargs that are inside the uboot configuration for the beaglebone black.

Running 'printenv bootargs' before running the splexport command returns the following:

```
bootargs=console=ttyO0,115200n8 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 ro rootfstype=ext2 rootwait
```

Does anyone know a reason why my kernel doesn't boot?

-----UPDATE-----
As suggested, I have tried with Uboot 2017 but I still get the same response - it says 'reading uImage' but does nothing more. Uboot 2017 is very different to setup compared to 2013; I had to export a uBoot.env file after setting the below (otherwise it would complain about falcon args file not being set in environment):

```
setenv falcon_args_file args
setenv boot_os 1
setenv spl_load_image_fat_os uImage
setenv falcon_image_file uImage
```

I'm completely stuck; any more suggestions welcome :-)

Comment: Can you also please include the part where you write the args file after doing spl export?  And you're setting bootargs prior to running spl export as well, yes?  Please include the full log where you're loading uImage and fdt and setting bootargs, thanks!

Comment: Hi Tom - thanks for the reply. Apologies for not coming back until now; I was given something else to do so unfortunately this got sidelined. I'm back on this now. I've edited the post with the information you requested - does this help answer my question?

Comment: Hmm, can you do printenv bootargs before spl export?  Thanks!

Comment: Hi Tom - I've added the output to the original post. Hope this helps?

Comment: Is it significant that I have two entries for the device tree when I run spl export - "Using Device Tree in place at 80f80000, end 80f8c103" and "Using Device Tree in place at 80f80000, end 80f8f103"? What do the warnings stating 'subcommand not supported' mean?

Comment: Hmm, that all looks correct.  Is there a reason you're so far behind in releases?  v2017.07 is the latest.

Comment: No reason other than laziness - I'm using an older version of buildroot and this version of uboot was the one it had configured. I'll try building with uboot 2017 over the weekend and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: I have tried with the new uboot and updated the original post - same problem; just stays at 'reading uImage' and does nothing more. Any other ideas?